# Make rebuilding target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, target, recipe

I have a make target which is not a file name.

```
BUILD_DIR := <my build directory path>

build : $(BUILD_DIR)
    recipe

release : build
```

I observed that when I call `build` for the first time, it executes the recipe of `build` which is expected. However, when I call `release` followed by `build` it re-executes `build`. I have a clue on why this is happening, I read from GNU make references that -

> If you write a rule whose recipe will not create the target file, the recipe will be executed every time the target comes up for remaking.

Do we have a way to avoid `build` getting re-built ? I cannot simply call `release`. My expectation is to call `build` followed by `release` and `build` should not re-execute when `release` is called. I know I can simply remove the dependency of `release` but I am not preferring it that way. Can someone recommend a better way out ?

Comment: Any clues on this ? Let me know if any additional information is needed. But I guess the question is self explanatory.

Comment: What is `recipe`?  What *does* it generate?  Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] (i.e. complete `makefile`) that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @G.M. The recipe has nothing to do with the question that I have asked. Please read the question before commenting. But just for the sake of answering -  it generates an elf file nothing else.

Comment: So why not replace `build : $(BUILD_DIR)` with `file.elf: $(BUILD_DIR)` and add the dependency `build: file.elf`?

Answer (score 1):

The reason people are having a hard time replying is because your question is not at all clear.  What exactly does *my expectation is to call build followed by release and build should not re-execute when release is called* mean?  The term *call build* has no meaning in make: you don't "call" targets.  If you showed us exactly what commands you ran and the output you got, and explained what you wanted instead, then it would be much simpler to provide correct answers.

I will assume you mean, you run `make build` followed by `make release` and you don't want to create a file named `build` and you don't want the `build` recipe to be run when you run `make release` even though you **do** want `build` to be listed as a prerequisite of `release` in the makefile.

In short, that's not possible.

Make decides whether a file should be rebuilt by comparing the modification time of the target file against the modification time of the prerequisites.  If any of the latter are newer than the former, it runs the recipe.  If the former (target) doesn't exist then the recipe is always invoked.  Make doesn't maintain any sort of database between invocations saying when the last time a recipe was run or what targets were built the last time it ran: the only "database" it has is the modification times on the filesystem.

Since your `build` target doesn't create a file, how is `make` supposed to know when you *do* want the `build` target recipe to be invoked, and when you *do not* want the recipe to be invoked?

Answer (score 0):

Release should have the build artifacts as prerequisites instead of the (phony) build target.

Comment: Removing `build` from `.phony` doesn't resolve the issue. It is still trying to re-build `build`. The reason is same as I stated before

Comment: @CoolCamel I mean build is not a file created by the build target rule and hence it is a phony target. Nevermind that detail, focus on build artifacts as prerequisites to release. If you can't focus go read the manual about phony targets.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try and give you a practical answer, but you really should look at the other answers for better practice.

---

You want the opposite of `.PHONY`. `.PHONY` is a phony target that is always built, you want a non-fake target that gets rebuilt conditionally... which is a regular target.

You want `make` to remember that it already called `build`, but make doesn't have any cache, it just uses files and mtime, so that's what you do:

```
BUILD_DIR := ./target

.PHONY: build release

$(BUILD_DIR):
    mkdir $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/file.elf: $(BUILD_DIR) src.c
    cp src.c $@

.built: $(BUILD_DIR)/file.elf
    touch $@

build: .built

release: build
```

```
$ make release
mkdir target
cp src.c target/file.elf
touch .built
$ make build
make: Nothing to be done for 'build'.
```

The idea is in order to considered the codebase to be "built" (`.built`), a list of artifacts (in this case, just `$(BUILD_DIR)/file.elf`) needs to be up-to-date. And each such artifact has its own recipe.

Then `make release` will re-run the `build` target, but it will do nothing if the codebase is `.built`.

---

Notice how you could just skip `.built` and have `build` directly depend on `$(BUILD_DIR)/file.elf` as was suggested in the comments:

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/file.elf: $(BUILD_DIR) src.c
    cp src.c $@

build: $(BUILD_DIR)/file.elf
```

If you instead go your way:

```
build: $(BUILD_DIR)
    cp src.c $(BUILD_DIR)/file.elf
    touch $@
```

Then when `src.c` gets updated, `file.elf` doesn't get rebuilt. To fix that, you'd have to list all the sources as dependencies of the `build` target, and that means your build won't be incremental: whenever it needs to rebuild anything, it will rebuild everything.

---

The only reason I can think of to actually use something like `.built` is if it's not feasible to list all the artifacts, for example if you build recipe creates a complicated, uncached set of artifacts:

```
.built:
    bazel clean
    bazel build //... # builds all packages
    touch $@

build: .built
```

Or if the build is not specified by a file:

```
.has_container_image:
    docker build --no-cache .
    touch $@

build: .has_container_image
```